# jQuery: hide a link that appears another column based on value of previous column

Tags: jquery

I have been googling and searching around in stackoverflow and searching `http://oscarotero.com/jquery/`.  I see and have tried using some of the **traverse** elements like **.find** and **.next**, but i know I just don't have the understanding of how to lay this code out correctly.

I have a 5 column html table with 20 rows of data, columns are[id, name, location, available, [update]
last column [update] has a hyperlink that links to another function that will update my db, changing the value that appears in column 4 from 'Y' to 'N'

Using jquery, I want to hide the link this appears in column 5, when the value in column 4 (which is the **available** column) equals N

So what I was attempting to do, to no avail, was write code that would say:
find input tag type=text and value = W, go to the next  tag and hide the

Can anyone explain how to do this or let me know if it is not possible?

I create a fiddle here: `http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/9XV28/`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="text"][value="W"]')
    .closest('tr')  //navigate up to the parent row
    .find('td:nth-child(4) a') //grab the link inside the 4th cell of that row
    .hide() // hide it.
```

Comment: Wow that worked.  I don't even want to tell you how many .next's I had in my code, never even thought to try .closest.  Thank you so much.  Amazing!